# Apache2 enable .ini mod in /etc/php5/mods-available

Tags: apache-2.2, xdebug

One can use the `a2enmod [module]` command to enable mods located in `/etc/apache2/mods-available`. But what about mods in `/etc/php5/mods-available`? When I try to enable a mod in this directory (eg. xdebug), I get the following error:

> ERROR: Module xdebug does not exist!

Yet, `/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini` exists.

I understand `a2enmod` may work only with *.load files (it makes sense since *.ini files are just configuration files) but then what's the correct way of enabling modules located in `/etc/php5/mods-available`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `php5enmod` to enable PHP modules.

Comment: Indeed it's a PHP module, not an Apache module.. Thank you!